# Nginx serving two Angular-Apps: Config with multiple location blocks causes issues

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location

I created a website and a respective admin-backend with Angular and want to serve it using Nginx via Docker. The website should be available via *'mydomain.com/'* whereas the backend should be available via *'mydomain.com/backend/'*. Getting the website running works perfectly fine. But the path resolution for the backend just does not work.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Webpage
FROM node:16 as build-webpage

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY ./webpage /usr/local/app/

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build # ng build

# Backend
FROM node:16 as build-backend

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY ./backend /usr/local/app/

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

# Nginx
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build-webpage /usr/local/app/dist/webpage /usr/share/nginx/html/webpage
COPY --from=build-backend /usr/local/app/dist/backend /usr/share/nginx/html/backend

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

The nginx.conf contains these location blocks:

```
location /backend/ {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/; # backend should get appended (due to root)
  index  index.html index.htm;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}

location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/webpage/; # only / is appended, so webpage is appended manually
  index  index.html index.htm;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```

When I then try to open *'mydomain.com/backend'* or *'mydomain.com/backend/index.html'*, the following log is generated by Nginx:

```
open() /usr/share/nginx/html/webpage/backend/index.html failed …
```

As it seems to me, Nginx matches the "/-Location" instead of the "/backend/-Location", since the "webpage"-folder is part of the directory Nginx resolves.

According to various blogposts, Nginx chooses the "best-fitting" location branch when resolving a URL. Therefore, "/backend/" should be chosen. Also, I tried to replace `location /backend/` with `location ^~ \/backend\/`, so that the caret enforces that branch since it is before the "/-Location" in the config file. Unfortunately, that made no difference either.

So I was blessed if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any critical errors, except serving an angular app usually done using `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` and `try_files $uri $uri/ /backend/index.html;` in your case. Don't you want to try using common web root for both? `COPY --from=build-webpage /usr/local/app/dist/webpage /usr/share/nginx/html`, `COPY --from=build-backend /usr/local/app/dist/backend /usr/share/nginx/html/backend`, `root /usr/share/nginx/html;` ?

Comment: About your question, your assumption about nginx behavior is correct. The only reason I could see is that the different configuration or server block is actually used by your nginx server.

Comment: I found the problem. As @IvanShatsky said, there were no critical errors regarding my nginx config. However, I haven't set the "base-ref" for the backend angular project correctly to the respective subfolder. Once I fixed that, everything was working like expected